# benefit of using systemu instead of open3?

Tags: ruby

The systemu page says:

> systemu can be used on any platform to return status, stdout, and stderr of any command.  unlike other methods like open3/popen4 there is zero danger of full pipes or threading issues hanging your process or subprocess.

(https://github.com/ahoward/systemu)

Could anyone explain this a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Methods [like popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-c-popen) and its various spinoffs are convenient and are part of the expected API for a full I/O library.

However, they must be used either casually or carefully because they are prone to deadlock. By casually, I mean, if you both write and read from the command, it's still OK as long as you either don't write a lot or don't read a lot. By carefully, I mean, you can move large amounts of data, but only if you keep the inner details of the operation in mind and deliberately engineer against deadlock.

Imagine writing lots of stuff to your *popened* command and then reading a result. If you write more than a pipe will buffer, then your process will sleep. That's OK in practice, most of the time, but what if the command has to write a lot of stuff? Now *it* may sleep and not finish reading input that you are sending. You won't finish sending input so you will never wake up and read results.

Deadlock!